# why my network is not automatically configured when I reboot my server?

Tags: networking, debian, openvpn

I am having a little problem, I am using a VPN (with openvpn), and it starts auto when the server starts, the problem is that every time I have to set something like this

```
route add -net 10.108.**.** netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 10.108.**.**
```

If I make a ifconfig its the eth0 and eth1 and lo and tap0

```
tap0      
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1a:ad:6b:69:3c:83
inet addr:10.108.24.253  Bcast:10.108.24.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::18ad:6bff:fe69:3c83/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:481 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
```

and I dont understand why doesnt work, at my interfaces I have

```
up route add -net 10.108.**.0 netmask 255.255.255.** gw 10.108.**.1
down route del -net 10.108.**.0 netmask 255.255.255.** gw 10.108.**.1
```

So, I have to write this

```
route add -net 10.108.*.0 netmask 255.255.255.** gw 10.108.**.1
```

Any idea of what could be???

(I use Debian6)

Comment: What type of VPN are you running?  Is `10.108.**.1` on the other side of the VPN?

Comment: yes, that is the other side of the vpn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are having an issue relating to timing.  I suspect the VPN link isn't fully established when your route statements are being run.  If I were you, I would look really closely at the VPN tool you are using, and use the functionality within the VPN to update your routes once the connection has been established.

Comment: yes, I think its that too, any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: Like I said, set the route in the VPN.  Since you haven't said what vpn you are using I can't really sat much more.

Comment: Thanks, I am using openvpn, I solved it thanks for your answer, making and post-up of my network